# Is it possible to sort an array of objects in this specific way using sort()?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

Sorry for not putting the specific sort in the title but I couldn't word it properly.

I'm sorting a list of file objects that have details such as name, date uploaded and category and I need to sort it in such a way that the last uploaded file is push to the top and the rest of them aren't sorted.

So for example, if I had the list sorted from oldest to newest in descending order I still want the newest one at the top.

The lists are already sorted in terms of category, date, etc. when returned from the database so I just need to further sort it after.

It has to be done in a function that gets passed to a sort().

Comment: Everything is possible show what you have done so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) is not necessarily stable, as long as you sort just by one property as in the first result.

You need another value for moving *equal* (resulting with `0`) items to the right place, here with additional value of `id`, which are in creation order.

```js
var data = [{ id: 0, date: '2017-01-01' }, { id: 2, date: '2017-01-01' }, { id: 5, date: '2017-01-02' }, { id: 6, date: '2017-01-05' }, { id: 9, date: '2017-01-06' }, { id: 19, date: '2017-01-11' }, { id: 24, date: '2017-02-01' }, { id: 67, date: '2017-02-01' }, { id: 80, date: '2017-02-11' }, { id: 90, date: '2017-02-21' }, { id: 101, date: '2017-02-23' }, { id: 149, date: '2017-02-28' }, { id: 163, date: '2017-03-01' }, { id: 190, date: '2017-03-02' }, { id: 321, date: '2017-03-05' }, { id: 444, date: '2017-03-17' }],
    lastDate = data[data.length - 1].date;

data.sort(function (a, b) {
    return (b.date === lastDate) - (a.date === lastDate);
});
console.log(data);

data.sort(function (a, b) {
    return (b.date === lastDate) - (a.date === lastDate) || a.id - b.id;
});
console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Another solution would be, to use [`Array#pop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) for the last item and [`Array#unshift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/ushift) for inserting at top place of the array.

```js
var data = [{ id: 0, date: '2017-01-01' }, { id: 2, date: '2017-01-01' }, { id: 5, date: '2017-01-02' }, { id: 6, date: '2017-01-05' }, { id: 9, date: '2017-01-06' }, { id: 19, date: '2017-01-11' }, { id: 24, date: '2017-02-01' }, { id: 67, date: '2017-02-01' }, { id: 80, date: '2017-02-11' }, { id: 90, date: '2017-02-21' }, { id: 101, date: '2017-02-23' }, { id: 149, date: '2017-02-28' }, { id: 163, date: '2017-03-01' }, { id: 190, date: '2017-03-02' }, { id: 321, date: '2017-03-05' }, { id: 444, date: '2017-03-17' }];

data.unshift(data.pop());
console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of solutions for this. As simplest solution you can use something like https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#orderBy

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by simply compound your sorting algorithm:

```
sortingLabels = ["date uploaded", "category", "date"]
myArray.sort((a,b) => {
  for (l of sortingLabels) {
    const comparison = compare(a,b,l)
    if (comparison == 0) {continue}
    return comparison
  }
})
```

Now all you have to do is implement a `compare(a,b,label)` function that returns `-1`,`1`, or `0` based on the `label`.

***Note:*** The for loop `for-of` works in ES2015+, which is most modern browsers and Node.js. However, if you need to support significantly older browsers, you might want to consider using a general `for-loop`